# VSCode doesn't show code suggestions for discord.py

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, discord, discord.py

I've installed the discord.py rewrite and am trying to code using vscode, but intellisense doesn't work with it. It works just fine when using numpy, or basic python modules, but it doesn't work for discord.py.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    message. # this shows no suggestions aside from other words in the code
```

Here's a [image: picture]

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow, so if you're going to downvote please leave me a comment as to why. Thanks!

Comment: If you ever find an answer please do tell me.

Comment: @AnchithAcharya Unfortunately, I never found one, and I've since abandoned the project because of it. If you find a solution, do tell me as well.

Comment: I have not found the solution, but there is an interesting observation. The autocomplete does indeed work, just not everywhere. For example when I type message. it shows nothing but if I type discord. or client. it shows a whole lot of suggestions. And the description for those suggestions seem to be exactly the same as found in the documentation for discord.py. I am new to python but know c/c++. I planned to make a bot solely using my knowledge of the latter, and with help from autocomplete suggestions. But I guess I have to resort to youtube tutorials now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Intellisense what type the message parameter is so that it can do the auto complete.
You can do this by doing the following
`async def on_message(message:Type):`

Comment: `async def on_message(message:discord.Message):` doesn't seem to fix it, neither does `async def on_message(message:discord.message.Message):`

Comment: For me, `async def on_message(message: discord.Message):` worked

Answer (score 0):

Old question but there is a solution. With the **Pylance** extension on discord you can tell it where discord.py is downloaded and it will recognize it.

In your working directory make sure you have a settings file

```
working_directory
└───.vscode
│   |   settings.json
```

Then within that file include a key/value pair as follows:

**Generic Example**

```
{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["Path/To/Folder/Containing/Dicord/Python/Code"]
}
```

**Windows Example**

```
{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["C:\\Users\\YOURUSERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python38\\site-packages"]
}
```

When you run `pip install -U discord` it will tell you where the installation folder is